# An enclosing instance that contains <my reference> is required

Tags: java, instance

> An enclosing instance that contains  is required

Below is the code. `positionObj` is the object that I am trying to use and it is giving me the above error.

It's unclear why.

```
package toolBox;
import toolBox.Secretary.positionObj;    

public class PositionManagement {
    public static HashMap<String, Secretary.positionObj> main(String vArg){
        positionObj newPosition=new positionObj();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You're trying to use the non-static inner `positionObj` class without an instance of `Secretary` for it to belong to.
A non-static inner class must belong to an instance of its parent class

You should probably change `positionObj` to a normal class or a static inner class.

Alternatively, you can write `someSecretary.new positionObj()` to create an instance of the inner class that belongs to the `someSecretary` instance.

Comment: agreed, but this general statement is a bit unclear. could you provide an example or point me somewhere that might better explain this? thanks

Comment: yes. i realized when trying to debug that if I made my positionObj to static that it worked (in its Secretary class). I am happy and all that it now works, but thanks for the pointer. Will look into actual cause of this error.

Comment: The actual cause of the error is that you didn't give a parent instance.  Do not use non-static inner classes unless you really need one _and you understand how they work_. http://c2.com/ppr/wiki/JavaIdioms/NoPublicInnerClasses.html

Comment: both solutions work perfectly [1- making the positionObj class static and 2- using OuterClass.new classObj() ]. thanks

Comment: Yes.  However, you need to understand your code base well enough to figure out which one is correct.

Answer (score 26):

First create an object of Outer class. In this case I think "Secretary". Then create positionObj. Like this,

```
Secretary x = new Secretary();
Secretary.positionObj y = x.new positionObj();
```

Comment: THANK YOU! ... I've used Java since v 1.0 and I didn't know you could do that!

Comment: Or you can do it inline 
Secretary.positionObj y = new Secretary().new positionObj();

Answer (score 0):

The correct generic signature would be

```
public static HashMap<String, positionObj> main(String vArg)
```

you dont need to qualify positionObj since you already import it.

However,  I am pretty sure a main method must conform to the signature below. If you intend to have main be the main method for your program, change the signature to

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {...}
```

you can create a separate static method that returns a Map and invoke it from main.

As a note, all classes should begin with a capital letter, positionObj, should be PositionObj.

Comment: hey, left out some code. agreed about the case. the class does return something, but the error is here and i am unclear why.

Comment: @jason, i dont think you can return anything from main.