# What is the difference between (self) and (self,) in python method?

Tags: python, class, methods, definition, self

[image: method in class of M2DET published]

Let's see a code sentence `def consturct_modules(self,):`.

I have a simple question about why this method defines `(self)` as `(self,)`.

It seems to me that `(self)` is proper form.

What is the difference?

Comment: It's probably unintentional, but totally valid to leave a trailing comma in the argument list

Comment: thank you. I understand . There was not problem which raise error maybe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No difference in terms of function. Trailing comma in function argument lists is allowed starting from Python 3.6. See: https://bugs.python.org/issue9232

In terms of style, the trailing comma is not recommended in this particular case. See: [Should I add a trailing comma after the last argument in a function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087742/should-i-add-a-trailing-comma-after-the-last-argument-in-a-function-call)

Answer (score 1):

The trailing comma makes no difference in parameter lists (though it is a syntax error in Python 3.5 and earlier).

For multi-line parameter lists, I prefer to have trailing commas on each line to make diffs smaller and more uniform.

Comment: A ha! , I'm using python 3.7 so there was not syntax error. good ! thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between `(self) and (self,)`.

The main advantages are that it makes multi-line lists easier to edit and that it reduces clutter in diffs.

Check this link :- [Why are trailing commas allowed in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597901/why-are-trailing-commas-allowed-in-a-list)