# How do dynamicly concatenate functions executed on object in Python?

Tags: python

Let's assume that one has one list: `lst = [name, surname, phone, email]` and one dictionary `data={"name": "Mary", surname: "Smith", "phone": "123", "email": "mail@domain.com"}`.

I want to preapre code like this:

`sample_object.add('user').prop('name': data['name']).prop('surname': data['surname']).prop('phone': data['phone']).prop('email': data['email']).do()`

The problem is that I want to make id dynamically, the static parts are: `sample_object.add('user')` and `.do()`. The middle part is dynamic that means that my list can contain e.g. 7 elements and the values could be various.

Theoretically, I can concatenate strings in for loop and then use `exec` on the string but I found it as an ugly solution. How can I do it in a pythonic way?

Comment: Why not give your object an update method that takes the dictionary, or the dictionary unpacked into keyword arguments? The fluent interface doesn't seem like it's giving you any benefits.

Comment: The object is created from the third part class.

Comment: .prop is a method that set's the property simillar to `setattr`?

Comment: That is not how you code in Python. Functions in Python are dynamic enough to do what you like to do in one shot. `.prop(name=data['name'], surname=data['surname'], ...)` and the function would be something like `def prop(**kwargs)`.

Comment: @KlausD. as I mentioned the prop function is a third part function. It was primarily written in Java. More precisely in Groovy, and even more precisely it is Gremlin.

Comment: @Vince W, I'm not sure if I understand you correct. Could you expand your question?

Comment: Are you on Jython, or how do you use the Java function?

Comment: I use Python, I use it as you can read here: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gremlin-python

Comment: I see that what you're trying to do is similar to the Builder pattern, maybe you should check this answer on Builder pattern in python -
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977279/builder-pattern-equivalent-in-python#11977454

Comment: Show us definition of that `prop` method.

Comment: `prop` is short from `property` method which is here: https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/3.2.6/gremlin-python/src/main/jython/gremlin_python/structure/graph.py