# Raise "not editable" exception

Tags: python, exception

I have a class Book, which has a property `editable`, along with others:

```
class Book():

    def __init__(self, name, ..., editable=True):
        self.name = name
        ...
        self.editable = editable
```

`Book` has methods `get_details()`, `set_details()` and `delete()`.

If `editable` is set to `False`, I want to raise an Exception in `set_details()` and `delete()`, stating that the Book is not editable.

I have gone through the Python docs but I haven't been able to find anything similar to a Not-Editable exception.

Is raising a custom exception the best way to do this, or can anyone suggest another workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: One example: `class NotEditableException(Exception): pass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the property decorator for restricting mutable attributes.
For instance consider:

```
class Book(object):
  """My book object is a wrapper for details"""

  class Details(object):
    """My details object"""

  def __init__(self):
    self._details = Details()

  @properties
  def details(self):
     return self._details
```

trying to run

```
book = Book()
book.details = new_details
```

will raise an [AttributeError](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.AttributeError). To turn this "off and on" using the editable flag, you could add the following decorated method:

```
  @details.setter
  def details(self, new_details):
    if self._editable:
      self._details = new_details
    else:
      raise AttributeError("Attribute cannot be set when Book is not editable.")
```

As for delete, Python's garbage collector should cleanup old variables as long as you're smart with scope :)

For more on properties and setters, [check out this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627002/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-use-getters-and-setters). If you are planning on making the "book" immutable after a certain point, I would recommend looking into a [factory design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26193004/1369019) (where you would programmatically construct the book class before exposing it) opposed to turning on and off a flag.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know python does not have this type of exception. You can define custom Exception class of your own.

```
class NotEditableException(Exception):
    def __init__(self,message="Not editable"):
        super(NotEditableException,self).__init__(message)
```

Now you can raise your exception the following way.

```
if not self.editable:
    raise NotEditableException("This is your error message");
```