# Java class accepting different objects on same argument in one constructor

Tags: java

This is my old code and I decided to refactor it in order to make refuse easier, but now I wonder if it can be done even simpler.

```
public class AccountConstraint {
    private Range<Integer> accountId;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;

    public AccountConstraint(Object accountId, final String username, final String password, final String email) {
        if (accountId instanceof Integer) {
            accountId = new Range<>(accountId);
        }
        this.accountId = (Range<Integer>)accountId;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Range<T> {
    private T min;
    private T max;

    public Range(T min, T max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public Range(T value) {
        this.min = value;
        this.max = value;
    }

    public T getMin() {
        return min;
    }

    public T getMax() {
        return max;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + min + ", " + max + "]";
    }
}
```

With this you can create an AccountConstraint that has as accountId either an `Integer` or a `Range<Integer>` and ensures that it is always saved as a `Range<Integer>`.

Background information here is that you should be able to just enter an integer like `5` and that it will be automatically stored as `Range(5) = Range(5, 5)` then.

The code works fine, but it seems a bit messy. So I came up with the following improvement:

New constructor:

```
public AccountConstraint(Object accountId, final String username, final String password, final String email) {
    this.accountId = Range.<Integer>getRange(accountId, Integer.class);
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;
}
```

New method:

```
public static <T> Range<T> getRange(Object object, Class<? extends T> clazz) {
    if (clazz.isInstance(object)) {
        object = new Range<>((T)object);
    }
    return (Range<T>)object;
}
```

It also works and it seems better in my opinion as it can be done as a one-liner now, but can it even be done better? More specifically, can the `Class<? exends T>` be left out?

And a small question: Should it be `Class<T> clazz` or `Class? extends T> clazz`?

Regards.

**EDIT: Implemented the Builder Pattern as suggested, because there is a possibility that there will be more arguments that can be overloaded. New code:**

```
package dao.constraint;

public class AccountConstraint {
    private Range<Integer> accountId;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;

    private AccountConstraint(Builder builder) {
        this.accountId = builder.accountId;
        this.username = builder.username;
        this.password = builder.password;
        this.email = builder.email;
    }

    public Range<Integer> getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public static class Builder {
        private Range<Integer> accountId;
        private String username;
        private String password;
        private String email;

        public Builder() {
            this.accountId = null;
            this.username = null;
            this.password = null;
            this.email = null;
        }

        public Builder accountId(final int accountId) {
            this.accountId = new Range<>(accountId);
            return this;
        }

        public Builder accountId(final Range<Integer> accountId) {
            this.accountId = accountId;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder username(final String username) {
            this.username = username;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder password(final String password) {
            this.password = password;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder email(final String email) {
            this.email = email;
            return this;
        }

        public AccountConstraint build() {
            return new AccountConstraint(this);
        }
    }
}
```

An extra nice feature now is that the fields that are not-mandatory do not need to be filled in anymore as the default value is `null` for them anyways.

Comment: Erm, most people would create two constructors.

Comment: You could create a builder having two different methods `.withUniqueValue()`, `.withRange()`

Comment: You seem to be trying to write Python code in Java.

Comment: Isn't your one-liner require creating a supporting 4-liner? Isn't alternative constructor neater? Also, Why constructors? Cannot you apply your polymorphism to simple methods?

Comment: 99% of the time decalaring a variable Object is a bad idea

Comment: Also; writing to minimise lines of code over readability is only asking for trouble

Comment: @fge Could you be so kind to provide the Builder pattern as an answer with supportive code?

Comment: @skiwi done, on request.

Answer (score 6):

Neither, use overloading...

```
public AccountConstraint(Integer accountId, final String username, 
         final String password, final String email) {
    this(new Range<Integer>(accountId), username, password, email);
}

public AccountConstraint(Range<Integer> accountId, final String username, 
         final String password, final String email) {
    this.accountId = accountId;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;
}
```

Comment: I do not want to use overloading as there might be a lot of arguments having this same construct, which would lead to 2^(those_arguments) constructors. If `age` for example would be stored, then it would need to use the same construct as `accountId`.

Comment: @skiwi Is one AccountConstraint going to take (for example) accountId and age simulaneously? Or will there be two instances of AccountConstraint, each one taking accountId or age?

Comment: @skiwi If you are going to have a large number of arguments that varies, then the [Builder Pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007355/builder-pattern-in-effective-java) is what you want. If you don't own 'Effective Java' from Josh Bloch ... you should.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use a builder, like so (code to be improved):

```
public final class AccountConstraintBuilder
{
    private Range<Integer> accountId;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;

    public AccountConstraintsBuilder()
    {
    }

    public AccountConstraintsBuilder withUsername(final String username)
    {
        this.username = username;
        return this;
    }

    // password, email...

    public AccountConstraintsBuilder withUniqueValue(final int value)
    {
        return withRange(value, value);    
    }

    public AccountConstraintsBuilder withRange(final int min, final int max)
    {
        accountId = new Range<Integer>(min, max);
        return this;
    }

    public AccountConstraint build()
    {
        return new AccountConstraint(accountId, username, password, email);
    }
}
```

This would then allow to have only one constructor on `AccountConstraint`: the one with a `Range` as an argument. Also, builders are a great place to enforce constraints: your instance constructor has nothing to do but "blindly" accept its arguments.

Note: I guess instance parameters in your `AccountConstraint` could be final, too.

Note2: this could be a static inner class to `AccountConstraint` instead; and a static factory method could be created so that you could do:

```
AccountConstraint.newBuilder().withUsername().etc().etc().build();
```