# When is a method 'closed under its type'

Tags: groovy

I am learning Groovy and I learned how to overload operators. I am using *Groovy In Action* to learn. The example they give is of a `Money` class and they overload the `+` operator by overriding the `plus()` method.

All their `plus()` return `Money`. I decided to write my own code and made all  my `plus()` return `Integer`.

**SSCCE:**

```
class Money{
    private Integer amount

    Money(Integer amt){
        amount = amt
    }

    /*
     * Shows how to overload the + operator
     */

    Integer plus(Money more){
        int total
        total = this.amount + more.amount
        return total
    }

    Integer plus(Integer more){
        int total
        total = this.amount + more
        return total
    }

    Integer plus(BigDecimal more){ // multiple dispatch
        int total = more.plus(this.amount)
        return total
    }

    @Override
    String toString(){
        return "$amount"
    }
}

def buck = new Money(1000)
println buck + 1000.0G
```

My question is: What are the benefits of returning `Money` instead of `Integer` ? This is a purely hypothetical question but why would one want to 'close a method under its type`? I know`java.lang.String` does that. No matter how you operate on String, you get a String (for some methods, I mean).

Also, why can I overload `plus()` in so many different ways ? Where is this `plus()` initially defined ?  Or am I overriding because I am inheriting them from somewhere ?

I know the questions sound sort of stupid but these are the confusions in my head while learning Groovy

Comment: What happens if I have 3 `Money` objects, `a`, `b` and `c`, and do: `a + b + c`

Comment: @tim_yates Code blows up. I see it now =D It will be like adding a `Money` to `Integer` and BOOM !

Comment: But if you return `Money` from `plus`? -- edit :-)

Comment: @tim_yates It does not blow up =D is it always good to close a method under its type because it allows method chaining ? *In simple terms, it allows to create fluent APIs* ?

Comment: I guess the answer is _"it depends"_ ;-)  For things like `plus` (an overridden operator), I would say the answer is almost universally yes for the chaining thing. I can think of contrived examples where this wouldn't be the case however. And with Groovy, you could of course add a `plus( Money )` method to Integer, but this would tend to break the [Principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) ;-)

Comment: Obviously, an easy example of where this shouldn't hold true is `Integer.div( Integer )`, which returns a `BigDecimal` : `assert 3.div( 4 ).class.name == 'java.math.BigDecimal'`

Comment: @tim_yates If you post all this as an answer, I will accept it =)

Answer (score 1):

Closing the operation under its type allows you to chain multiple examples of the operator and adds to clarity/ease of maintenance because it is what people expect. For instance, if you had some code like this

```
def firstMoney = new Money(15)
def secondMoney = firstMoney + 10
```

The natural assumption, I'd suggest, is that `secondMoney` would also be of the class `Money`. If your operator returned an `Integer` that would be mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Look. Therm, that you asked for have a mathematical root. It means, that an closed operation will return object from same set. [wiki Closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(mathematics))

It's not only Groovy related, and it's more general, that it seems.

First of all, it's a contract, that allows you freely combine any operations, you need, until they returns an object of the same type.
You can thrust class, when they follow this contract, and this will not produce unexpected, or positional-dependant behaviour.(what is obviously awful)

For example, many math classes, like vectors are declared in ode of two ways
Vector (2D float vector)

1. void incr(Vector that){ this.x += that.x; this.y += that.y }
2. Vector incr(Vector that) {/*same code */ return this }

Second solution allows as to chain methods:
`v.incr(anotherVector1).incr(anotherVector2)`

Many classes like [builders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5007355/1601606) uses that to shorten their usage.

About second question: operator overloading.
As I know, it's a groovy compiler feature, which changes each operator to corresponding method call using duck typing. It will throw an MME at runtime, if there is no such method providen.

About *"So many ways"*. Its a poverfull combination of static method overloading and [Multimethods](http://mrhaki.blogspot.ru/2009/09/groovy-goodness-multimethods-or.html).
So, at invoke time language will select proper method from class, using their arguments real type.