# Object communication in Java with no Static variables with getters and setters

Tags: java

I have a JPanel where i keep track of the mouse pointer position when it moves. I store that into some fields. How can I access the getter to read the fields of an already created object, within another object?

This is just an example, i'm struggling to get object communication without using static variables.

Some code:

```
class MainPanel extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener {

  public int mouseX, mouseY

  public MainPanel(){
    this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    ...
  }
  public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

    this.MouseX = e.getX();
    this.MouseY = e.getY();

  }

  public int getX(){

  return this.MouseX;
  }

  public int getY(){

  return this.MouseY;
  }
  ...
  }
}

class Something{

*** I want to, for example, print on console the XY coordinates of the -object-
 MainPanel. ****
}
  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several possible solutions.

## Instance Scope

If you need access to `MainPanel` from `Something` scope (i.e., several methods in `Something` will use `MainPanel` and the intermediate states in `MainPanel` are important).

Pass your `MainPanel` instance to `Something`.

**Use a constructor:**

If `Something` can't do its job without `MainPanel`:

```
class Something {
    private final MainPanel mainPanel;
    
    public Something(MainPanel mainPanel) {
        this.mainPanel = mainPanel; 
    }

    public void myMethod() {
        System.out.printf("Mouse cordinates: %d x %d\n", mainPanel.getX(),
                mainPanel.getY());
    }
}
```

Initialization code:

```
MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel();
// ... put panel in frame, etc
Something something = new Something(mainPanel);
```

**Use a setter:**

If `Something` can do its job even without `MainPanel`:

```
class Something {
    private MainPanel mainPanel;
    
    public void setMainPanel(MainPanel mainPanel) {
        this.mainPanel = mainPanel
    }

    // my other methods
}
```

Initialization code:

```
MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel();
// ... put panel in frame, etc
Something something = new Something();
something.setMainPanel(mainPanel);
```

---

## Method parameters

If you only need the state of `MainPanel` in the scope of a method (you don't want to hold a reference to `MainPanel` in `Something`) you can pass a instance of `MainPanel` where it's needed. This is the best strategy for independent methods. Even if several methods in `Something` need access to `MainPanel`, there is no point to store `MainPanel` as a field unless the methods are somehow "working together" on an instance of `MainPanel`:

```
public void myMethod(MainPanel mainPanel) {
    System.out.printf("Mouse postion: %d x %d\n", mainPanel.getX(),
            mainPanel.getY());
}
```

Usage example:

```
MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel();
Something something = new Something();
something.myMethod(mainPanel);
```

---

Finally, as well as thinking about variable scopes, you should think about what does your API really need in order to work. `Something` needs access to `MainPanel` or just to the mouse coordinates? If it only need the latter, have `Something` deal directly with `x` and `y` or introduce an intermediate object (if you can write an interface it is even better) and decouple `Something` from `MainPanel`:

```
class MainPanel extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener {

  public int mouseX, mouseY;
  // everything else

  public Point getMousePosition() {
      return new Point(this.mouseX, this.mouseY);
  } 
}
```

And in `Something`:

```
public void myMethod(Point mousePosition) {
    System.out.printf("Mouse position: %d x %d\n", mousePosition.getX(),
            mousePosition.getY());
}
```

Why is it better? `Something` is not aware of `MainPanel`, it only knows about `Point`. You can create `Points` out of anything you want and send it to `Something`:

Usage example:

```
MainPanel mainPanel = MainPanel();
MyOtherComponent myOtherComponent = MyOtherComponent(); 
Something something = new Something();
something.myMethod(mainPanel.getMousePosition());
something.myMethod(myOtherComponent.myMousePositionMethod());
// or even
something.myMethod(new Point(1,1));
```

Comment: I thought this. But in my real life Something class it requieres info from 3 or 4 different objects. Is it a good practice to pass the information using the constructor?

Comment: @GabrielA.Zorrilla, yes, it is ok. But if you dont like constructor with a lot of parameters and if you will use same objects for creating different other objects, than you'l probably need use `builder pattern`

Comment: Beat me to it. 3 or 4 is reasonable. Else use [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007355/builder-pattern-in-effective-java)). Only use setters if `Something` can do its job without the objects. Also, be ware of concurrency issues.

Comment: Good stuff Anthony. Obrigado!

Comment: Glad to be of service :) De nada! (Covers Spanish and Portuguese :)).