# Initialize Complex class in java

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a complex class generated from a WSDL file.  This class contains several other classes which in turn contain also other classes. There are more than 5 levels overall.

In order to initialize an instance I need to create several objects; the initialization code for creating an object of this class is around 100 lines.

Is there a good pattern to use for cases such as this? I created a wrapper around each class, and a wrapper around those wrappers. Is this is how it is done?

Comment: Are you sure this is the best design? Smells incredibly fishy.

Comment: Without knowing the specific case, I can only say that whenever creating an instance is complicated, you should use either the factory or the builder pattern

Comment: Thanks for reply, I will have a look on these patterns. Unfortunately I can not post the code due to intellectual rights. But, it is as follows . In order to initialize the parent class I want to initialize a list of classes first. Example. let us assume I need to create an object of a person class, I need first to initialize an object of the name class which is set as first name and last name and title,  and then I need to create an object of age class which have a code such as adult and  age value and so on.   This is enforced by the java proxy class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a good pattern to use for cases such as this?

Yes, it's called builder pattern. I prefer to use [fluent interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007355/builder-pattern-in-effective-java). Another example you can find [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html).