# scala - Referencing inner class type in outer class constructor

Tags: scala

I would like to access inner class type in the outer constructor, like :

```
// does not compile, MyInner now know from outer constructor
class MyOuter(private val mySet: Set[MyInner]) {
  class MyInner(index: Int)
}
```

The Inner class must be non static (outside an object) as it may access some fields of the outer class instance.

The code below compiles, but the field is mutable:

```
class MyOuter() {
  class MyInner(index: Int)

  private var mySet: Set[MyInner] = _
  def this(_mySet: Set[MyInner]) {
    this()
    mySet = _mySet
  }
```

This seems to be scala-specific as the below Java code is legal:

```
import java.util.Set;

public class Outer {

    private final Set<Inner> mySet;

    public class Inner {
        private final int index;

        public Inner(int _index) {
            index = _index;
        }
    }

    public Outer(Set<Inner> _mySet) {
        this.mySet = _mySet;
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: It doesn't make sense for a constructor to take an argument of a type that is defined in terms of the thing you are trying to construct.

Comment: @emilianogc which pattern do you suggest then ?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve. You can't do instantiate new MyInner from outside to pass to the CTOR of MyOuter. In Java inner class means something else.

Comment: @Maxim I would like to creaate a mapping between a map and an array of array. The inner class contains the two indices. For the purpose of this post, I have reduced the problem to a set and an array

Comment: @Maxim I would like to reproduice the builder pattern : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007355/builder-pattern-in-effective-java

As the inner class is not instanciable outside of the outer class unlike java, how should I do in scala ?

Comment: @ogen in Scala if it's a simple builder just use default values. If you still want it why not making the builder not an inner class?

Comment: @Maxim It is not a simple builder, I have made a separate class to handle this with package-private modifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This phrase: "The Inner class must be non static (outside an object) as it may access some fields of the outer class instance." explains why what you want is impossible: you are trying to create an instance of a class, that accesses fields of an instance of another class, that *does not yet exist*.

And no, it would not work in java either. Note the  `static` qualifier in the answer to the question you referenced in your comment. It has the same effect as moving your inner class to a companion object - static inner classes in java can only access static members of the outer class.

This would, I think, be the right solution for your case - make a companion object, and move the inner class there. No, you do not need to access members of the instance, that has not been constructed yet :)