# Why have package private constructor in @Builder in Lombok?

Tags: java, builder, lombok

Recently, I came across Lombok's builder and frankly loved it. 
Then I came to know that Builder pattern is described at many resources for instance Effective Java.
[Somewhat like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007355/builder-pattern-in-effective-java)

Now, in this pattern, the constructor is kept private so that the instance of the class could only be created by only using the builder.

But, in Lombok's documentation for the builder [Builder's Documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder)
the constructor visibility is kept package private.
What could be the reasons behind keeping it as package private?

Comment: It think it might be to enable inheritance for builders, as a single private constructor would prevent inheritance. I'm not sure if @Builder actually supports inheritance though. You should try asking this in the [lombok group](https://groups.google.com/group/project-lombok) if you don't get any answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question described in detail at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/362265/builder-with-constructor-or-factory-method. I see that your question is more specific to Project Lombok's design so you might want to join the community. But in general I agree with the accepted answer and the way Lombok implemented the builder pattern using a factory method.