# Method which the return-type is the same autoclass?

Tags: java, return-type, autoclass

I have a doubt. Be the following Java Class code:

```
public class myClass{
    public myClass myMethod(){
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

1) How could myMethod return type be the auto-class? It is no logican sense for me.
2) What does it mean?

Thanks :)

Comment: When you say "the auto-class" do you just mean the same class as that in which the method is defined? If so, why *shouldn't* you be able to do that? For example, why shouldn't the `substring` method of `String` be able to return a `String`? What should it return instead?

Comment: Another common case to return `this` and thus the own type is the [builder pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007355/builder-pattern-in-effective-java).

Comment: @LuCio or methods on immutable types, e.g. `BigDecimal.add`.

Comment: Only *one* doubt? I **deeply** admire your steely determination.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes, this is the definition i used for. In your example, seams to me a little scramble to define a method inside a class, returning the same class. Seems to me more natural a method that returns an class from "outside", because "outside" means that that class is "completely deifned", having a "closed form". A method refering to it's class inside this class looks like a "recursivity". substring could be defined, for example, in a StringUtils class. More organized.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Where did you read this?

Comment: @NathanLima you can develop your own classes in that way if you like. The language designers simply didn't see it as a necessary restriction on the language.

Comment: @NathanLima *Where did you read this?* The first line of your question. *I have a doubt.* You have doubt. How much doubt? **A** single doubt. That's very admirable, but not very believable. Even Jay Z has ninety-nine problems.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch You are wrong. "A" is an indefinite article in english language, not a numeral. You are reffering to "A doubt" as "A only one doubt", and this is not correct. Words as "A" or "An" are indefinite articles, while "The" is a definite article. Both words aren't numerals!!!!!

Comment: @NathanLima Can I have a dollar? Can I get a coke? How about a witness? A is indefinite. Doubt is singular. I have *doubts* myself, but I try not to *doubt* myself. You might find [this stack](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions) relevant to your interests.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some spelling mistakes in questions, Seems like you are asking how can it is possible that method return type is same as class.

**The Answer is:** this is because Return type is just used for specifying datatype and class is Data type like Integer String.

This is example of factory design pattern

moving back to your question, myMethod return myClass means it return an Object of myClass 
We can perform any operation on return value which you can perform on myClass object

Answer (score 0):

Well, taking a look at your responses, guys, I consider my question should be not clear.

I don't have problemns in understand return type. It is perfectly natural return a class.

My doubt (not just one doubt in the life, but one doubt among many other) consists on the method return the same class in which this method is implemented. It looks like some kind of "loop", or "recursivity". I imagine a method returning a class IF this class is outside this method, because in this case the external class will be fully implemented. When a method return the same class in which this method is declared, in my thought the class is not fully implemented yet.

That was my doubt but I think today it is more clear to me.

Thanks to all responses.