# error with inner class object

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
class YY
{

   int a=0;
   void putValue(int m)
   {
        a=m;
    inner x=new inner();
        x.display();
   }
   class inner
   {
    void display()
        {
       System.out.println("value of a:"+a);
        }
   }
}

class InnerYY
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
    YY ob=new YY();
    ob.putValue(90);
    YY.inner i = new YY.inner();
    i.display();
   }
}
```

while running this program i'm getting the following error...

InnerYY.java:27: an enclosing instance that contains YY.inner is required
        YY.inner i = new YY.inner();
                     ^
1 error

Comment: possible duplicate of [An enclosing instance that contains <my reference> is required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297857/an-enclosing-instance-that-contains-my-reference-is-required)

Answer (score 4):

Your `Inner` class is non-static, so you havee to instantiate it with an instance of `YY`.

In your case that is `Inner inner = ob.new Inner();`

Note that:

- If you want that class public, you can refer to it as `YY.Inner` (but you can't instantiate it that way)
- by convention you must use capitalized class names (`Inner` rather than `inner`). That said, I think it's worth mentioning that usually in Java (but that's not as imperative as the capitalized class name) the opening curly bracket stays on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

To reference `YY`, `InnerYY` would have to actually be inside `YY` (moved before the closing break). However you then couldn't have a static main function, which appears to be what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

You try to create non-static inner class from static call YY.inner(). So you need to create object yy = new YY() and then call inner = new yy.inner(). Or to make inner class static.