# How can I resolve "an enclosing instance that contains X.Y is required"?

Tags: java, netbeans, inner-classes

I am developing a small desktop application in Netbeans. This is my first program and I am facing a very strange type of error. I know I did some thing wrong but unable to trace what I am doing wrong :(

Please help me in resolving this error.

Description:
I have a default package `Src` and I am creating new Java classes in this package as required. Along with other classes I made a class `X` like this:

```
public class X
{
    public class Y
    {//some member functions and variables exist here}

    public class Z
    {//some member functions and variables exist here}

    //some member functions and variables exist here
}
```

Now I need to create instance of one of the inner classes in some other class that exists in the same package, like this:

```
public X.Y oY = new X.Y();
```

but I am getting the following error:

> an enclosing instance that contains X.Y is required

Please help me in resolving this error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [An enclosing instance that contains <my reference> is required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297857/an-enclosing-instance-that-contains-my-reference-is-required)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

First of all you have to create an object of X class (outer class) and then use `objX.new InnerClass()` syntax to create an object of Y class.

Try,

```
X x=new X();
X.Y y=x.new Y();
```

Comment: Wow! I leaned something today! Strange syntax. Very nice! +1

Comment: Does anyone know why they made the language this way? What purpose does this serve?

Comment: Sorry for the late response here, I believe it's to be able to support both static nested classes and non-static nested classes.  I'm not an expert, but from what I am reading, I believe this is to force subordinate classes to be members of an instance of a the parent (non-static) and create a different syntax for subordinate classes that don't require a parent (static). 
 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Answer (score 36):

You want to declare static inner classes: `public static class Y`.

Comment: Because the OP didn't mention it needs to stay non-static. If he needs the enclosing instance, he'll comment about the compiler error from making it a static and learn even more from his question.

Comment: +1 for this answer - the accepted answer isn't entirely complete as it assumes the class is required from a non-static context.  In my case, this was not true.

Answer (score 10):

Declare Y as static to avoid creating instance of X.

```
public class X
{
    public static class Y {
    }
}
```