# Miss default constructor for entity with EmbeddedId

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

Always when i try to get list of entities from JPA Repository i got exception like this

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No default constructor for entity:  : pl.hycom.hyper.hyebok.model.ServiceEntity$Id; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:  : pl.hycom.hyper.hyebok.model.ServiceEntity$Id
```

What is missing in my entity. I have both non-args constructor and all-args constructor in Embeddable class and outer class. I can't find a solution for this issue.

My entity below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "he_service")
public class ServiceEntity implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private Id id ;
    private String name;

    public ServiceEntity() {
    }

    public ServiceEntity(Id id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Embeddable
    class Id implements Serializable {

        public Id() {
        }

        public Id(String serviceId, String clientId) {
            this.serviceId = serviceId;
            this.clientId = clientId;
        }

        @Column(name = "serviceId")
        private String serviceId;
        @Column(name = "clientId")
        private String clientId;

        public String getServiceId() {
            return serviceId;
        }

        public void setServiceId(String serviceId) {
            this.serviceId = serviceId;
        }

        public String getClientId() {
            return clientId;
        }

        public void setClientId(String clientId) {
            this.clientId = clientId;
        }


   }
```

Repository  method there

```
   @Query(value= "SELECT s FROM ServiceEntity s " +
            "WHERE s.id.clientId = :clientId")
    List<ServiceEntity> findByClientId(@Param("clientId") String clientId);
```

Comment: Try make your `Id` class static.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your inner `Id` class is non-static which means it creates a constructor

```
class Id implements Serializable {

    public Id(ServiceEntity arg0) {
    }
    // …
}
```

Change it to a `static` class

```
static class Id implements Serializable {
    // …
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the `Id` class static. Otherwise it'll require an instance of `ServiceEntity` to instantiate.

Answer (score 0):

You can also declare `Id` in file of its own `Id.java` like `class ID { }` or `public class ID { }` if need to keep in different package.

Related information in general: [How can I resolve “an enclosing instance that contains X.Y is required”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619505/how-can-i-resolve-an-enclosing-instance-that-contains-x-y-is-required)

Maybe the problem is that `Spring` fails on this

> an enclosing instance that contains ServiceEntity.ID is required

Answer (score 0):

Im new to Java, and have been doing an exploration in full stack java and angular application.

I created a service that allows me to perform CRUD operations and store my data in an in-memory database.

I was trying to display my data in `http://localhost:8080/users/Joe/all-todos` 
and I get the error that the OP has raised.

To solve mine, I had to create a default constructor like so: 

     `// JPA expects a default constructor in my entity class ToDo
     protected ToDo() {}`

Note here that I am using JPA.  I just add that default constructor to my entity class and run my java application and it rendered the data.

Hope this helps in some way with regards to the error message.