# Call Async From An Extending Class - Error is not an enclosing class

Tags: android

I have a class (DisplayIMageFromFTP_3) which extends RecyclerViewer Class (MyRecyclerViewAdapater)

```
public class DisplayImageFromFTP_3 extends AppCompatActivity implements MyRecyclerViewAdapter_3.ItemClickListener
```

How I populate the adapater

```
private void callRecyclerAdapter() {
    
    adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter_3(this,
            arrayListString_url_abs_fileName,
            arrayListString_url_fileName,
            arrayListString_url_fileExtension,
            arrayListString_url_fileDate,
            arrayListString_url_fileSize);
    adapter.setClickListener(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

MyRecyclerViewAdapter_3:

```
class MyRecyclerViewAdapter_3 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter_3.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<String> arrayListString_url_abs_fileName,
        arrayListString_url_fileName,
        arrayListString_url_fileExtension,
        arrayListString_url_fileDate,
        arrayListString_url_fileSize;

String url_abs_fileName,
        url_fileName,
        url_fileExtension,
        url_fileDate,
        url_fileSize;

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ItemClickListener mClickListener;
PopupWindow popupWindow;
private Context pContext, aContext;                                                                        //Context for Popup Window (got from onCreateViewHolder)

// data is passed into the constructor
MyRecyclerViewAdapter_3(Context context,
                        ArrayList<String> url_abs_fileName,
                        ArrayList<String> url_fileName,
                        ArrayList<String> url_fileExtension,
                        ArrayList<String> url_fileDate,
                        ArrayList<String> url_fileSize) {
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.arrayListString_url_abs_fileName = url_abs_fileName;
    this.arrayListString_url_fileName = url_fileName;
    this.arrayListString_url_fileExtension = url_fileExtension;
    this.arrayListString_url_fileDate = url_fileDate;
    this.arrayListString_url_fileSize = url_fileSize;
}

// inflates the row layout from xml when needed
@Override
@NonNull
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, parent, false);
    pContext = parent.getContext();
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

// binds the data to the view
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    url_abs_fileName = arrayListString_url_abs_fileName.get(position);
    url_fileName = arrayListString_url_fileName.get(position);
    url_fileExtension = arrayListString_url_fileExtension.get(position);
    url_fileDate = arrayListString_url_fileDate.get(position);
    url_fileSize = arrayListString_url_fileSize.get(position);

    Context mContext = holder.ivHorizontalGrid.getContext();
    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(url_abs_fileName)
            .thumbnail(0.05f)
            //.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
            .error(R.drawable.error).
            into(holder.ivHorizontalGrid)
    ;

    holder.ibDots.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view_item) {

            url_abs_fileName = arrayListString_url_abs_fileName.get(position);
            url_fileName = arrayListString_url_fileName.get(position);
            url_fileExtension = arrayListString_url_fileExtension.get(position);
            url_fileDate = arrayListString_url_fileDate.get(position);
            url_fileSize = arrayListString_url_fileSize.get(position);

            setupPopUpWindow(view_item);
        }
    });
}
// total number of rows
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayListString_url_abs_fileName.size();
}

// stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    ImageView ivHorizontalGrid;
    ImageButton ibDots;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ivHorizontalGrid = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivHorizontalGrid);
        ibDots = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ibDots);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        //Log.d("LOG", "zzz_Click: " +view);
    }
}

// convenience method for getting data at click position
public String getItem(int id) {
    return arrayListString_url_abs_fileName.get(id);
}

// allows clicks events to be caught
public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
}

// parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
public interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}

//Popup Window
private void setupPopUpWindow(View view_item) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) pContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view_layout;
    view_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dots_menu_layout, null);

    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(view_layout,560, 740, true);
    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(view_item,-153,0);

    //Display FileName
    TextView tvFileName = view_layout.findViewById(R.id.tvFileName);
    tvFileName.setText(url_fileName);
    tvFileName.setSelected(true);                                                               //android:ellipsize="marquee"

    //Display Sub Text (Extension . Date . Size)
    TextView tvSub = view_layout.findViewById(R.id.tvSub);
    tvSub.setText(url_fileExtension.toUpperCase() +" \u2022 "+url_fileDate +" \u2022 " +url_fileSize);

    //MENU ~ SHARE
    LinearLayout ll_share;
    ll_share = view_layout.findViewById(R.id.ll_share);
    ll_share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            downloadFileForShare();
        }
        private void downloadFileForShare() {

            new DisplayImageFromFTP_3.Async_GetImageFromFTP(this).execute();
        }

    });
}
```

}

Now I'm trying to call an Async task from DisplayImageFromFTP_3 class like this:

```
new DisplayImageFromFTP_3.Async_GetImageFromFTP(this).execute();
```

and getting this error:

```
Error: DisplayImageFromFTP_3 is not an enclosing class
```

I would like to avaoid using static as suggested by Android Studio because it causes problems for a lot of objects in DisplayImageFromFTP_3, so perhaps I need the correct context?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this answer:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619505/how-can-i-resolve-an-enclosing-instance-that-contains-x-y-is-required
```

I was able to use this logic:

```
DisplayImageFromFTP_3 x = new DisplayImageFromFTP_3();
DisplayImageFromFTP_3.Async_GetImageFromFTP y = x.new Async_GetImageFromFTP(pContext);
y.execute();
```