# Call an overriden method from the super class

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I have a question about overriding methods.
if i have class a that has a method that can be overriden by the subclasses but is called in the superclass

```
public class a {
  //this is the main class
  public a() {
       //etc code
       callMethod();
   }
   void callMethod() {
       //do nothing here. will be overriden in subclas
  }

  public class b extends a {
      void callMethod() {
           //actually impliment here
  }
  }
```

how to I call class b's implimentation of the method from class a

Comment: Neither of your classes extends the other, so there's no overriding here...

Comment: Note: It's recommended to start class names with a capital letter and not to call overrideable methods in constructors.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you meant:

```
public class b extends a
```

In this case the code:

```
a aa = new b();
```

Will call `b.callMethod()`. Note that calling overriden (non-private) methods from a constructor is a bad idea.

Comment: its not actually from the constructor its from another method

Comment: As far as I can see You have a class named `a` with a method named `a` and no return value - this **is** a constructor calling `callMethod()`. Except that your could run just fine, or maybe I don't understand the question?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the visibility of the `callMethod` method to `protected` then `b.callMethod()` is what would be called, even from the superclass.

The protected keyword tells Java that the method is visible to subclasses; and by extension makes it virtual.

Comment: yeah but it needs to be called from the superclass

Comment: @Jeremy: And I'm telling you it will work fine if it's protected.  The semantics on default access members are a little more blurry.

Comment: but the superclass does not know the name of the subclass

Comment: @Jeremy: It doesn't need to.  That's the nature of overriding...since your `A`'s concrete class will be `B`, it will use the implementation found in `B`.  I would appreciate if you would try it rather than just not believing me.  Then if you still have questions or you find I'm wrong, keep asking.

Comment: i tried it but it didn't work. I am not sure if I did something wrong. The superclass method was protected and the subclasse method was protected. I called the method from within the superclass but it did not run the subclass version

Comment: @Jeremy: Please post your exact code in the form of an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: I ended up getting it to work. turns out after i put the protected in, I put the overriding method in the wrong class, but I figured it out. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

The following results in a compiler error: "An enclosing instance that contains Demo.A.B is required." That is discussed in: [An enclosing instance that contains <my reference> is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297857/an-enclosing-instance-that-contains-my-reference-is-required). So, the answer is: You can't do that. Write it into its own class file instead of a nested class.

```
package Demo;

import Demo.A.B;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A test = new B();
    }
}
```

---

### Broken

```
Package Demo;

public class A {

    public A() {
        callMethod();
    }

    void callMethod() {
        System.out.println("Called from A");
    }

    public class B extends A {
        @Override
        void callMethod() {
            System.out.println("Called from B");
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Working

(A.java)

```
Package Demo;

public class A {

    public A() {
        callMethod();
    }

    void callMethod() {
        System.out.println("Called from A");
    }
}
```

(B.Java)

```
package Demo;

public class B extends A {
    @Override
    void callMethod() {
        System.out.println("Called from B");
    }
}
```

Comment: so here is how my program actually works. I have one class that provides by root functionality for all my other classes. One of the functions the root class peforms is sliding in and out my panels. I need the superclass method that slides in and out the panels to call the subclass implimentation of the method that will run when the panels are finished loading.

Comment: @JeremyKaplan It sounds like you've got a design issue. When you say panels, are you talking about panels in a windowing system (Swing / AWT)? Why do they need to be the same name / be an override?

Comment: they are not the same name. I have the superclass controlling the sliding in and out of the panels. Each of my subclasses extends the superclass.

Comment: I meant same method name, but ok.... we're making progress. As an override, if you do `A a = new B()`, then `a.callMethod()` will be the method from `B`. You simply need to instantiate the right object.

Comment: the only issue with this is that b is not created within A, it is created within a whole different class.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot but you can create constructor for class b, call workflow will be next `fileds a - > constructor a - > method from a-> constructor b - > method from b`

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class a {
  //this is the main class
  public a() {
       //etc code
       callMethod(); 
   }
   abstract void callMethod();
}

  public class b extends a {
      void callMethod() {
           //actually impliment here
  }
}
```

But don't do this. This calling method from constructor in superclass a maintenance nightmare and bad design.