# an enclosing instance that contains Queue.Node is required

Tags: java, linked-list, queue, binary-search-tree, fifo

So I'm working on a Binary Search Tree and need to do a Level Order Traversal. I will be printing out all the keys that are on the same level.

Problem I'm having right now is that I need to create a FIFO Queue. I have the Queue created but when I try to add the node to the queue I keep getting the `an enclosing instance that contains Queue.Node is required` error message. Can someone help me out on what I'm doing wrong.

This is my Level Order Traversal at the moment.

```
public void LevelOrder_Traversal(BST_Node node){
    Queue temp=new Queue();


    Queue.Node newNode=new Queue.Node();

    temp.enqueue(node);
```

This is my Queue class

```
public class Queue{
public class Node{
    private Integer key;
    private Node next;

    public Node(){
        this.key=null;
        this.next=null;
    }

    public Node(int key){
        this.key=key;
        this.next=null;
    }
}

int size;
Node head;

public Queue(){
    head=new Node();
    size=0;
}

public void enqueue(Node node){
    if(size==0){
        head=node;
    }

    Node curr=head;
    while(curr.next!=null){
        curr=curr.next;
    }
    curr.next=node;
    size++;
}

public Node dequeue(){
    Node temp=head;
    head=head.next;
    size--;

    return temp;
  }
}
```

I found a couple of other posts that are similar to what I'm doing but I wasn't really understanding them that much. If someone would be so kind as to explain what I'm doing wrong and why it's wrong that would be great. Do I need to extend the Queue class or anything like that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [An enclosing instance that contains <my reference> is required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297857/an-enclosing-instance-that-contains-my-reference-is-required)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `Node` inner class is non-static. Non-static classes in Java have an implicit reference to their enclosing class, so they must be instantiated by an instance method of the outer class. Instantiating it like this

```
Queue.Node newNode=new Queue.Node();
```

is not valid, even though the `Node` class is `public`.

Declare it with the `static` keyword to fix this compile issue: the class can be logically made `static`, because its methods do not require knowledge of the enclosing `Queue` class.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. how would one go about converting a queue node to a bst node?

Comment: @k3vyw3vy Queue node has a single `next` link; a BST node has two links - `right` and `left`.

Comment: ok, so it won't work. is it possible to add a BST Node into a Queue Linked List or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: @k3vyw3vy Your BST classes should be separate from the queue classes. To do a level-order traversal you need to add nodes of your BST to a queue, so you need both a queue and a BST. The key of the node should be a BST node, not an `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

You declare:

```
public class Queue {
    public class Node {
```

This means that in order for a `Node` instance to exist, you *must* have an instance of `Queue`. Hence the message: "an enclosing [Queue in this case] instance that contains Queue.Node is required".

The quite ungainly syntax in order to obtain a `Node` with such a design is:

```
final Queue queue = new Queue();
final Node node = queue.new Node();
```

In general, you use this design if it is actually required for `Node` to have a `Queue` to be relevant at all. I have never seen that... Except for *private* inner classes.

But if your `Node` class can be created *independently* of a `Queue`, it must be declared `static`:

```
public class Queue {
    public static class Node { // <-- note the 'static'
```