# Can't create an instance of a Class

Tags: java

What's the reason why - `an enclosing instance that contains` appears when trying to instantiate a class?

Below is my actual code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    InterspecTradeItems_Type.Item_Type item = new InterspecTradeItems_Type.Item_Type();  
    // Error: an enclosing instance that contains InterspecTradeItems_Type.Item_Type is required

}


public class InterspecTradeItems_Type {
    public class Item_Type {

    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [An enclosing instance that contains <my reference> is required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297857/an-enclosing-instance-that-contains-my-reference-is-required)

Comment: If you don't need an instance of the enclosing class in the Item_Type, you should make it static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `Item_Type` is *inner class*. To instantiate an inner class, you must first instantiate the outer class. Then, create the inner object within the outer object with this syntax:

> InterspecTradeItems_Type.Item_Type item = new InterspecTradeItems_Type().new Item_Type();

Answer (score 2):

Since `Item_Type` class is not a static nested class, but an inner class of `InterspecTradeItems_Type`, you need an instance of the later to access the former.

So, to create an instance of the inner class, you should create instance of the enclosing class:

```
new InterspecTradeItems_Type().new Item_Type();
```

Of course another option is to make `Item_Type` a `static` class:

```
public class InterspecTradeItems_Type {
    public static class Item_Type {

    }
}
```

And then your code would work just fine.

Comment: ... or make Item_Type static. Also note that `Item_Type` *is* a nested class. All inner classes are nested by definition. JLS section 8.1.3: "An inner class is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly declared static."

Comment: Note that because `InterspecTradeItems_Type` is not `static` you need an instance of its outer class to instantiate it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis. From where did you infer that `InterspecTradeItems_Type` is an inner class of some outer class?

Comment: It seems to be in the same class body as `main`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis. We don't know that for sure. But anyways, if that is the case, then yes another enclosing instance would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `InterspecTradeItems_Type` is declared/defined in a class called `Main`, you need

```
InterspecTradeItems_Type.Item_Type item = new Main(). 
                                new InterspecTradeItems_Type().new Item_Type();
```

You have an inner class within and inner class. You need an instance of each outer class to get to it.

Answer (score 0):

To instantiate an inner class, you must first instantiate the outer class. Then, create the inner object within the outer object with this syntax:

```
OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();
```

So either use above syntax or make `Item_Type` class **static**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    InterspecTradeItems_Type.Item_Type item = new InterspecTradeItems_Type.
                                                                   Item_Type();  
    // Error: an enclosing instance that contains
                               InterspecTradeItems_Type.Item_Type is required

}    
public class InterspecTradeItems_Type {
    public static class Item_Type {

    }
}
```

Read [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) on Inner classes for more information.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    InterspecTradeItems_Type item = new InterspecTradeItems_Type();
    Item_Type item1 = item.new Item_Type();  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to have an object of inner class is

```
    InterspecTradeItems_Type.Item_Type item = new InterspecTradeItems_Type.new Item_Type();
```